# WPF DatagridTemplateColumn cell click event is not firing only if i click on the icon of the cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, datagridcell

I have a datagrid in WPF with some TextColumns and a TemplateColumn. These have different styles. Each TextColumn has the same BasicCell style with a click event which works fine if you click on one of the cells of the column. The TemplateColumn has TemplateColumnCell style. It contains a MaterialDesign icon and it looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit"  Width="0.5*" CellStyle="{StaticResource TemplateColumnCell}">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Edit" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The cell style of this template column, contains an EventSetter of PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, but it fires only when the icon is clicked. I want it to fire when you click on the cell, not necessarily on the icon.

```
<Style x:Key="TemplateColumnCell"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                     Handler="myTemplateCell_PreviewMouseDown"/>
    </Style>
```

Why isn't this working? And what could I do to make it work?

Comment: I can't reproduce behavior with `<Image>`, works as expected. Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I provided the style I am using. The event is not fired unless the icon is clicked.

Comment: You can wrap the icon into a transparent Grid. The Grid will automatically stretch to occupy the available cell's space and thus allows to handle mouse interaction i.e. act as an event source for mouse events.

Comment: I have added an answer to give you the options. In your posted code (the Style) you basically disabled the cell's mouse interaction (i.e. hit test visibility) by overriding the ControlTemplate without setting the Border.Background to a value other than NULL (for example Transparent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the complete cell to receive mouse interaction you must either add a container to the template that spans over the complete cell or override the `ControlTemplate` properly. Properly in this case means that you must set the `Border.Background` to `Transparent` in order to make it hit test visible.
An adequate container to host the content of a cell could be a `Border` or a `Grid` or anything that naturally stretches to occupy the full available space. The examples below use a `Border`.

Note that it is sufficient to set `SnapsToDevicePixels` on the parent element as it will be inherited. Therefore, if you set it on the root of the tree (e.g. `Window.SnapsToDevicePixels`), then the complete `Window` and all its child elements will inherit the value.

### Solution 1

Modify your column's cell template:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Border Background="Transparent">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Edit" 
                                 Width="15" 
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

### Solution 2

Modify your cell template (from your cell `Style`):

```xml
<Style x:Key="TemplateColumnCell"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

  ...

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border Background="Transparent">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```